# LaTeX scientific standards for thesis epigraph and dedication

Tags: thesis, epigraphs

I am a bit of noob with LaTeX, but I am enjoying learning it while I am doing my master thesis here. I've been wondering what would be the best scientific standards and LaTeX formats for dedications and epigraphs, since I wanna have those on my thesis.

Should it come before or after the abstract? Blank pages in between? I don't know much myself.
Also, what are the best formats/packages for each one?

I wanted to make a nice simple dedication to my brother that passed away. I tried a new chapter, but it looked kinda lame... Can anyone suggest something?
Also, is the sentence I used the most proper for such case? I am not native english speaker, so I can't be sure.

For the epigraph, I am using the epigraph package and forcing the epigraph to the bottom of a blank page, but I am still not 100% sure this looks good. Any suggestions?

Here's how my document starts:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    bibtotoc,
    cleardoubleempty, 
    idxtotoc,
    ngerman,
    openright
    final,
    listof=nochaptergap,
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\include{preamble}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

% Titelblatt
\include{content/title}
%\cleardoubleemptypage

\frontmatter

% Abstract
\include{content/abstract}
\cleardoubleemptypage

% Epigraph
\chapter*{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\large}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\epigraph{Somewhere, something incredible is waiting to be known.}{Carl Sagan}
\cleardoubleemptypage

% Dedication
\chapter*{Dedication}
To the memory of my beloved brother, Timothée.
\cleardoubleemptypage

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\cleardoubleemptypage

... Then list of figures, abbreviations, mainmatter and so on ...
```

So? Any feedback? I would be so thankful, this is very important for me.

Kind regards,

bpx.

Comment: Welcome to the site! And to LaTeX :) A lot of this question is really about style and not really about TeX-LaTeX at all. On those points, you should really talk to your adviser, have a look at what's common in your field - that sort of thing. It's not really what we do here, and it's very opinion based too. We can't really tell you what your document should look like (although we delve into that occasionally, usually if you ask us to do something that's normally discouraged) just how to make it look a certain way

Comment: Would it be possible to edit this question down so that just the TeX specific questions are left? (It would ideally be better to ask separate questions separately too. This is one of the ways Stackexchange is weird. We don't really open up threads in which to talk about all of your problems, instead we have Q & As, so each question should be its own question with its own answers underneath)

Comment: I'm sorry about your brother. My condolences

Comment: AFAIK, there are no scientific standards when it comes to dedication pages. usually they are used to express gratitude to a professor or to one's parents and family, etc. `In Memoriam` pages can be included as well, sometimes half-titles are used for these sort of pages. Or you could add additional pages after the title page. How you wish to express your gratitude is up to you, same goes for 'memorial pages'. As for the epigraph: Do you mean 'epitaph'? because AFAIK, an epigraph is something mathematical. Also, my condolences, I know how you feel, my kid brother died recently, too.

Comment: maybe this gives you an idea: http://rhi.scribenet.com/node/2224

Comment: Thanks, guys. As I said, I am noob in both LaTeX and scientific standards, so the idea of my thread was really asking more like personal opinions of people that are experienced with both things together. Sometimes I even have an idea of what I how I wanted it to look like, but I don't have enough TeX knowledge to accomplish it. So I at this stage I am thankful for any ideas.

Comment: Also, yes, I meant epigraph. It's a simple quotation that some people might use to initiate a chapter or a thesis itself, something meaningful that could represent what's coming next. And thanks, I'll check the link =]

Comment: About the questions, sorry if they are not directly located with LaTeX, my bad for being a noob here I guess... but I got the impression such questions were valid while seeing other people's questions on writing thesis with LaTeX. I'll consider editing or deleting to open a similar thread in another forum.

Answer (score 1):

The template seems to come from [Github](https://github.com/matthiasbeyer/git-einfuehrung/blob/master/main.tex) and it is not good. 
A few comments added.

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
%bibtotoc,
bibliography=totoc,
%cleardoubleempty, 
cleardoublepage=empty,
%idxtotoc,
index=totoc,
listof=totoc,% added
ngerman,
openright,% a comma was missing here
final,
listof=nochaptergap,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\include{preamble} % That should be input, not include
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% add the table of contents entry to the table of contents
\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

% Titelblatt
%\include{content/title}
%\cleardoubleemptypage

\frontmatter

% Abstract
%\include{content/abstract}
\cleardoubleemptypage

% Epigraph
%\chapter*{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\large}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\epigraph{Somewhere, something incredible is waiting to be known.}{Carl Sagan}
\cleardoubleemptypage

% Dedication
\addchap*{Dedication}
The text of the dedication here
\cleardoubleemptypage

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents
\cleardoubleemptypage

... Then list of figures, abbreviations, mainmatter and so on ...
\end{document}
```

---

As there is no license given, it should not be used. There are other/better templates available.